# How do I programmatically create a Unicode string in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm writing a spam filter that looks at lists of banned words. I'm trying to create Unicode strings which I can convert to accent-free strings using unidecode.

To make a Unicode string in the REPL, I could type

```
s= u'ShowTîtžForBłackDIçk'
```

but how do I do this when I don't know the string in advance? I need to apply the "u" operator programmatically.

I've tried
    s=unicode(unicodeString)

but this function needs me to state an encoding, and I'm not sure what underlying encoding is being used. I'm using the iPython (Jupyter) notebook, which can render Unicode in its web interface

Comment: 1) What is the value of `sys.version` in your Python? 2) Show us the code that creates the variable `unicodeString`.

Comment: If you're getting data from outside which you want to interpret as Unicode, you have to know what encoding is being used. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. Architecture concerns prevent me switching to Python 3 at the moment.

Comment: `s = u"%s" % myString`

Comment: @djangoliv error:
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

This doesn't happen when I type s=u'ShowTîtžForBłackDIçk'

Comment: @Helgi The data are being read in from a file, the encoding of which is not clear. The strings behave fine if I paste them in and add the u manually, but I need to do this programmatically.

Comment: @Louise. There is no general way to solve this problem. You either have to **know** the encoding of the source, or you have to guess based on the local settings (e.g. [locale.getpreferredencoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)).

Comment: @Louise, when you paste the strings, you have copied them, presumably from a text editor where you opened the file. The text editor handled the file encoding for you. This step can't be ignored or worked around. You have to understand that if you don't know the encoding, you'll have the Garbage In — Garbage Out situation. So please tell more about the problem. What's this file?

Comment: The file was dumped by a legacy system, I can't find out the encoding. It contains numerous accents and emoticons which render fine in Sublime Text.

What I would like to understand is how the u operator can happily build a Unicode object from a string it doesn't know the encoding of, and how I can do this programmatically. I could just use eval, but I'd prefer not to get into metaprogramming here.

Comment: @ekhumoro There must be a general way to solve this problem, because the Python interpreter is solving it perfectly.

Comment: @Louise, *something* already decoded it for you.  Whatever it is guessing, it is guessing correctly if you don't get garbage.  The `chardet` module can be used for guessing.  `str.decode(encoding)` or `unicode(str,encoding)` is how you convert from a byte string to Unicode string, but you have to provide an encoding.  The default if not provided in Python 2 is `ascii`.

Comment: @Louise, the `u` operator *does* know the encoding...it is the encoding of the source file or in the case of interactive the input terminal encoding.  Python 2 assumes the source file encoding is `ascii` unless you use a `coding` comment at the top of the source.

Comment: @Louise, maybe you can post a sample of the files you're working with. If there are several files, do they all have the same encoding? Until you know answers to this question, it might as well be garbage in — garbage out. Encoding guessing _might_ work, but please don't expect software to figure out the encoding automagically, this just won't happen. If it guesses wrong, and you load, say, a Windows-1251 file as Windows-1252, your spam list will be useless. And please read [this article on Unicode by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @Louise. Python doesn't "solve it perfectly": it's just a good guesser.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file as using Python's text reader. You have to define the encoding (it won't guess!):

```
with io.open("myspamwords.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as mywords:
    for line in mywords:
        print line.strip()
        print type(line)
```

This code will print each line and should show the type as Unicode.

If the results aren't decoded properly, change `encoding` to the appropriate character encoding.